# Highcharts - specifying order of stacked time series

Tags: graph, highcharts, time-series

Is there a way to specify the stacking order of time series in Highcharts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I have found is by ordering the series as they come in.
So, if I have series A, B, and C and I want it to be ordered by `B, C, A` then I add the series in `B, C, A` order such that series[0] = B, series[1] = C, and series[2] = A.
This is definitely a kludge because it would be nice to just sign a stacking index instead of resorting the series import order.

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented it that way, I was just wondering if anyone knew of a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an index to your series and then do series.update() to update the indexes. See below -

```
$(function() {
   var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
   plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
   },
   series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4],
      index: 1
   }, {
      data: [6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4],
      index: 2,
      id: 's2'
   }]
 });

 $('#button').click(function() {
    chart.get('s2').update({index: 0});
  });
});
```