# Highcharts legends value will be display in descending

Tags: highcharts

How can I sort the legends values (*40, 80, 10, 5*) in descending order?

The first value should be displayed in **Green** color and then other 3 will be any colors.

I tried with this code to display my first legend item in **green** color. Any Ideas for sorting the legend item?

```
{name: '{/literal}{$value.0.opt1}:{$a}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$a}{literal}, color: '#6B8E23'}, //green
{name: '{/literal}{$value.0.opt2}:{$b}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$sort.0}{literal}, color: '#A9A9A9'},
{name: '{/literal}{$value.0.opt3}:{$c}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$sort.1}{literal}, color: '#696969'},
{name: '{/literal}{$value.0.opt4}:{$d}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$sort.2}{literal}, color: '#FFFFFF'}]
```

*P.S. I am not familiar with jQuery.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution. you should sort the legend values before pass the values in data. then set the colors in array.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to sort the legend values quickly is to add your series in the order you want the legend to be in. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725570/highcharts-specifying-order-of-stacked-time-series/11740025#11740025) answer. You could try and create a javascript custom legend to do what you want as well - I have no quick answer for how to do that. If what you mean is that you want to order the **points** in a series in descending order you would first need to provide an example of what your actual data looks like: is it time based? category? linear?

To have the first value in a series be green you can use the point color like [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color).

Comment: is a dynamic value.. i have 4 numbers have to sort the numbers in descending order..

Comment: @Raj, so it is not 4 series but 4 data points in one series? If so, then just pre-process your data to do that. What is your xAxis datatype? Full example of the data can help us further answer the question.